# Parse Backend and Swift UITableview

Tags: uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to figure out how to display a query via Parse Backend in a UITableView.

I've read the documentation and succefull can display some querys on labels in a ViewController, but I`m having troubles to show the result inside a TableView.

I am a newbie trying programming with swift

Basically, I have this func inside my UITableView.

```
func retrieveParse(){
var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"Noticias")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        for object:PFObject! in objects as [PFObject] {
            self.timelineData.addObject(object)
        }

        let array:NSArray =       self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
        self.timelineData = array as NSMutableArray

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

}//

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:CellTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CellTableViewCell

// Configure the cell...

    let sweet:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject

    cell.tituloLabel = sweet.objectForKey("sobre") as UILabel

return cell
}
```

I just want to show some informations inside a UILabel, I don't know if my func is correct but, when I try to run the code I've receive a error :

```
0x112682662: nopw %cs:(%rax,%rax) Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_l386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
```

Comment: Make the table work with simple strings, add some logging, then, if the simple table works, add the PFObject part. Break it down and work out where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a look on parse.com example:
https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic

You need to implement PFQueryTableViewController. And override queryForTable method. Since parse.com gets data asynchronous, I think your problems comes from that.

Comment: I would love an example in swift as well. I have been struggling with this for a while. Thanks!

Comment: Which was your issue with Swift? Could you provide your full code(in github for example ) to understand what issue is?
I have implemented this with Objective C, without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty convinced that this line is not correct:

```
cell.tituloLabel = sweet.objectForKey("sobre") as UILabel
```

I don't think the `sobre` property is a `UILabel`. Try setting `cell.tituloLabel.text` to `sweet.objectForKey("sobre")`.

As we don't see the rest of your code, I'm assuming you didn't forget to implement `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`?